# WIX: How to detect if third-party application is installed?

Tags: wix

Is it any way in WIX to detect that a third-party application with a specified upgrade code is installed and what is it's installation folder? I can suggest a custom action is required, but what exactly to do in such custom action? Is it possible to detect such things in VBS custom action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really depends on the application. Most applications publish a registry key that can be used to detect them. In that case you just need a [`RegistrySearch`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) element, no custom actions necessary. If the application was installed via MSI, sometimes a [`ComponentSearch`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_componentsearch.htm) is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dotNetInstaller for configure it very well. With the help of registry search you can easily find out that the program is installed or not(Use product version / Product name for additional check)